# Why should we accept Islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, belief

The most fundamental question of all seems not to have been addressed on this site:

*Why should we accept Islam?*

I do not require that the answer derive from scripture itself; contemporary thought is equally welcome.

Comment: This would be both too broad and opinion-based I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this question is too broad, I would like to state that you should focus on 3 pillars in order to get answer to this question.

1. Allah
2. Quran
3. Mohammad(puh)

**Allah**

You should find answers to these questions:

- Why there must be a god?
- Why there can't be more than 1 god?
- Which attributes and characteristics should be carried by this one god?

In order to find answers to these questions, you should look for philosophical proofs and evidences. There are numerous different logical proofs on this issue. Some of them are:

- **Hudus:** Hudus means being exist later. Everything which has a beginning, should be non-exist before that beginning. Thus, there must be some power to make them exist, because a non-exist thing can't make itself exist. The universe has a beginning, thus there must be a huge power to create it.
- **Possibility:** Everything which become exist, had a chance to be non-exist before the beginning of existence. Thus, there must be some will to make this decision. Thus, the creator must be conscious.
- **Order:** If there is an order in somewhere, there must be some conscious to build that order and determine the rules. The universe has an order, which we try to find its rules by science. Thus, the creator must be so intelligent and wise.

There are also much more complicated philosophical evidences.

**Quran**

You should look for these questions:

- Can it be written by a human? If not, why?
- What characteristics of Quran differentiate it from a normal book?
- Do it's advises & prohibitions logically fine, or ridiculous?
- Does it contain any scientific errors?
- How can we know that it hasn't been changed?

**Mohammad(puh)**

- Do prophets have to exist?
- What characteristics should they carry?
- Was Mohammad(puh) really a prophet? If yes, how can we decide that?
- What kind of person Mohammad(puh) before become a prophet?
- What he brought? What he lost?

When you get answers to these questions, you would know why Islam. Its really a too broad question for here, but I tried to make more clear this way. You can also search for the works and speeches of Hamza Tzortzis, Nouman Ali Khan, Zakir Naik etc. I suggest you to look for speeches of people who become Muslims later, who has an academic background, who use their brains and logic to search for truth. Their way of thinking is very satisfying for me, because they don't make interpretations from their prejudges, rather they try to find knowledge first, and try to understand logic behind it.

Comment: This was a good effort and will likely form the basis for a number of future questions.